# Projective curve $x^3+y^3=2z^3$ in $\mathbb P^2$ singular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry

> Is the projective curve $x^3+y^3=2z^3$ in $\mathbb P^2$ (defined over $\mathbb{C}$) singular or nonsingular? If singular, what are the types of these singularities?

For an affine curve, one would find the points at which the equation, and its first derivatives (with respect to both x and y) equal $0$. Would I do something similar for a projective curve? How should I go about determining if this curve is singular?

Comment: One approach would be to examine $x^3+y^3=2$, $x^3+1=2z^3$ and $1+y^3=2z^3$ separately in their respective copies of $\Bbb A^2$.

Comment: Using @Arthur's idea, all you need to do is to check when the Jacobian of $x^3+y^3-2$ is of rank $0$ and that's the place where the curve is singular and similar for the other two affine curves in A^2

Answer (score 7):

Given a homogeneous polynomial $f(x,y,z)\in \mathbb C[x,y,z]$ of degree $d\gt0$, the curve   $V(f)\subset \mathbb P^2$
 (= the zero-locus $\{f=0\}$) has as  singularities the set of solutions $S \subset \mathbb P^2$ of the system $$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac {\partial f}{\partial z}=0 \quad (\ast)$$.
 Amazingly a point $s\in S$ **automatically** belongs to $V(f)$, i.e. $f(s)=0$, thanks to Euler's identity $$x\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}+z\frac {\partial f}{\partial z }=df(x,y,z) \in \mathbb C[x,y,z]$$ In your case $f(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3-2z^3$, so that the system $(\ast)$ has as only solution $x=y=z=0$, which which does not correspond to any point in $\mathbb P^2$.
Hence  $x^3+y^3-2z^3=0$ has no singularities: it is a smooth projective plane curve.

[Note that you don't have to do any calculations in the three canonical open affine subspaces $x=1,y=1, z=1$ of  $\mathbb P^2$.]